# Нужно выносить разные данные из одной страницы Ajax jq

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть функция и страница, на той странице много разных html блоков, мне нужно вытащить определенный и несколько штук. То есть вытащить картинку с классом: `img1` и засунуть ее в `div1` так же с картинкой `img2` и `div2`

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

            $('#btn1').click(function(){  
                $.ajax({  
                    url: "page1.html",  
                    cache: false,  
                    success: function(html){  
                        $("#content").html(html);  
                    }  
                });  
            });  
        });
```

Comment: Из того что вы написали и показали мало общего.. Зачем вам ajax?

Comment: @Haswell так я буду доставать блоки

Comment: Я не вижу у вас работы на сервере..Ajax  технология для взаимодействия с сервером без перезагрузки страниц.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#clickme').on('click', function(){
    $('#div2').append($('.image'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div1' style='background-color: yellow;'> БЛОК1:
  <img class='image' src='https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSKdpki1FyDbUGlSLqXk5s-w-ImMjZP6Y0DBNLjUSgPdb0rM1V5' />
</div>
<div id='div2' style='background-color: orange;'> БЛОК2:</div>


<button id='clickme'>
    Clickme!
</button>
```